# Fade out current element and fade in sibling element with the same class

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup which cannot be edited as it's generated by the server of which I do not have access. The server loads up all of the divs with the class 'contentBox', however it only shows the first one (the other three have '`display: none;`' added to them).

I want to add a div with an ID of 'switchButton', so that when it is clicked it fades out the first 'contentBox' div, then fades in the second 'contentBox' div etc. (so press it again, hides second, shows third div).

I need it to loop though, so if it's pressed 4 times, it goes back to the first box.

```
<div id="switchButton">Click Me</div>

    <div class="contentBox">Server side generated content</div>
    <div class="contentBox">Server side generated content</div>
    <div class="contentBox">Server side generated content</div>
    <div class="contentBox">Server side generated content</div>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I'm struggling with starting it at all, as I'm hopeless at indexing and loops. I have no idea how to target the next sibling as anything targeted with 'contentBox' is changing them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/avogad/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
var c = 0;                          // counter
var n = $('.contentBox').length;    // number of elements

// now using " ++c % n " you can loop your elements
// targeting the EQuivalent one using .eq() method. (0 indexed)
// % is called "reminder" or Modulo (AKA Modulus)   


$('#switchButton').click(function(){ 
  $('.contentBox').stop().eq( ++c%n ).fadeTo(500,1).siblings('.contentBox').fadeTo(500,0); 
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators
http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
http://api.jquery.com/eq/
http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/

<kbd>[Modulo playground](http://jsbin.com/otesub/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. What does the ++c%n do? I can figure out the the c & n refer to the variables, but that's about it!